# Faddeev-Popov ghosts in the Schwinger action principle

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Fixing the gauge in non-abelian theories results in the introduction of ghosts using the path integral formalism. Firstly, how does one fix a gauge in the Schwinger action principle formalism and secondly, how does one obtain ghost fields using the Schwinger action principle?

Comment: Schwinger's action principle is pretty much the *exact same thing* as the functional integral formalism.

Comment: I just want some technical details. You can't really impose the gauge condition using a delta functional like you do in the path integral.